# Question on scraping bullet information from Wikipedia

Tags: python, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, wikipedia

hopefully fairly easy question here. I'm trying to scrape data from a Wikipedia page to be put eventually into a dataframe using Python ([Page here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_neighborhoods_in_Arlington_County,_Virginia)). Specifically, I'm trying to put the list of neighborhoods (not in a table, but bulleted on the page) into an empty dataframe. I'm using BeautifulSoup and can get to where I have pulled the part of the wikipedia page I want, but can't get the names of the neighborhoods only (as opposed to the names and the weblinks). Below is what I have so far:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Neighborhood', 'Latitude', 'Longitude'])

arlington_hoods = requests.get(": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_neighborhoods_in_Arlington_County,_Virginia")

soup = BeautifulSoup(arlington_hoods.content, 'lxml')

content = soup.find(id='bodyContent').find_all('li)

print(content)
```

Once I run this, the output looks like this:

```
<li>Alcova Heights</li>
<li><a href="/wiki/Arlington_Forest_Historic_District" title="Arlington Forest Historic District">Arlington Forest</a></li>
<li><a href="/wiki/Arlington_Heights_Historic_District" title="Arlington Heights Historic District">Arlington Heights</a></li>
<li><a href="/wiki/Arlington_Ridge,_Virginia" title="Arlington Ridge, Virginia">Arlington Ridge</a></li>
<li>Arlington View / Johnson's Hill</li>
<li><a href="/wiki/Ashton_Heights_Historic_District" title="Ashton Heights Historic District">Ashton Heights</a></li>
<li><a href="/wiki/Aurora_Highlands_Historic_District" title="Aurora Highlands Historic District">Aurora Highlands</a></li>
<li>Aurora Hills</li>...etc etc.
```

I'm interested in only pulling the Neighborhood names (Alvoa Heights, Arlington Forest,...) and not the occasional weblinks into the "Neighborhood" column of the df DataFrame.

I think that I need to write a "for loop" to go through, but I'm not sure of the next step.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the results of `find_all()` and get the `text` attribute off each element.

```
for element in content:
  print(element.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def Get_Neighborhood(url):
    res = requests.get(url)
    #The names in the first ul tag
    html_parsed = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser').find('ul')
    html = BeautifulSoup(str(html_parsed), 'html.parser')
    out = []
    for x in html.find_all('li'):
        if x.string != None:
            out.append(x.string)
    return (out)

Neighborhoods = Get_Neighborhood('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_neighborhoods_in_Arlington_County,_Virginia')

for x in Neighborhoods:
    print (x)
```